# Finding shortest cycle in graph with positive weights

Tags: graphs

> Given a graph G, with all positive weights, find the shortest cycle length in O(V^3)

My idea is, negate al the edges, apply floyd-warshall algorithm and then for all $i$, find the largest $M[i][i]$ where $M$ is the final distance matrix, and then negate $M[i][i]$ and return.

Could this work? I know floyd can be used to detect a negative cycle, but if all edges are negative, can I apply it in this way to get the smallest cycle length?

Thanks

Comment: It might work. However, Dijkstra's name might be a better fit for you.